# Reset backcolor C# of 8*8 array

Tags: c#, winforms, button, backcolor

hey guys i got a question right now I have a 8*8 array of buttons. They can change color by clicking on them. I want to make a reset button so when you click on the reset button they will return to the backcolor black again. Button1 is the reset button. it is at the bottum of the code.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[,] btn = new Button[8, 8];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    btn[x, y] = new Button();
                    btn[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 30, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                    btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                    Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                    btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.SaveEventHandler);
            LoadFromFile();
        }

        void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
            switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
            {
                case "Red":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case "Black":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                default:
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
            }
        }

        void SaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveToFile();
        }

        private const string filePath = @"C:\testmap\test.txt";
        private void LoadFromFile()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                return;

            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            if (data == null || data.Length != btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1) * 2)
                return;

            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (y * btn.GetLength(0) + x);

                    string value = ((char)data[2 * position]).ToString() + ((char)data[2 * position + 1]).ToString();
                    Color color;
                    switch (value)
                    {
                        case "01":
                            color = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case "00":
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                        case "10":
                            color = Color.Green;
                            break;
                        case "11":
                            color = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                        default:
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                    }

                    btn[x, y].BackColor = color;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile()
        {
            Dictionary<Form1, int> d = new Dictionary<Form1, int>();

            byte[] data = new byte[btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1) * 2];
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (y * btn.GetLength(0) + x);
                    string value;
                    switch (btn[x, y].BackColor.Name)
                    {
                        case "Red":
                            value = "01";
                            break;
                        case "Black":
                            value = "00";
                            break;
                        case "Green":
                            value = "10";
                            break;
                        case "Yellow":
                            value = "11";
                            break;
                        default:
                            value = "00";
                            break;
                    }
                    data[2 * position] = (byte)value[0];
                    data[2 * position + 1] = (byte)value[1];
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the exact same code from the `Form1` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you initialized the buttons, you can set the backcolor back to black:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
   {
       btn[i, j].BackColor = Color.Black;
   }  
}
```

but what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx

Assuming you are not intending to use the control's Tag property for anything else, you could consider setting all affiliated elements to a particular Tag and then iterating through the form's controls to reset them to the desired BackColor, or you could simply set the Tag as your desired BackColor and have the reset button iterate as desirred.